# Networking for a business purpose with three different internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-shares

I have three broadband connection on three different floors. All are connected to a wireless D Link ADSL router. I want to connect them to a network and form a single network.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is to buy a **load balancer**, which is a router that can distribute WAN traffic over different connections, so as to maximize speed and efficiency. You can find one suitable to a SOHO (=Small Office/Home) network for (even) well under 100 US dollars.

All you have to do then is to turn the DHCP service off on your three D Link routers, thus automatically letting the LB (=Load Balancer) take care of assigning LAN Ip addresses. Plug each of your D Link routers into the LAN side of the LB, plug your internet connections into the WAN side of the load balancer, and you are done. Reboot all of your equipment (pcs, printers, whatever).

At this point all pcs belong to the same subnet, and they can easily talk to each other.